# SQL problems with complex forms on Symfony 2.8 after PHP upgrade from 5.6.30 to 7.0.20

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8

I was succesfully using an app in Symfony 2.8 with PHP 5.6. After I upgraded to PHP 7.0.20, I have problem to bind/submit a complex form with one-to-many relations.

The resulting error is:

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: "[Syntax Error] line 0, col 63:
>   Error: Expected Literal, got 'ORDER'" at
>   ..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php
>   line 44 {"exception":"[object]
>   (Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException(code: 0): [Syntax Error] line 0,
>   col 63: Error: Expected Literal, got 'ORDER' at
>   ..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:44,
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException(code: 0): SELECT s1 FROM
>   Prfuk\WebquotaBundle\Entity\Workplace s1 WHERE  ORDER BY s1.nazev
>   ASC at
>   ..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:39)"}
>   []

There is the missing part between `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`. Strange is that listing data is Ok, populating form fields to edit the record is also Ok, the problem is only while merging the `POST` request with the current form data, where I suppose the missing part of `SQL` is generated by doctrine.

Simple forms without relations to other tables work fine.

I am on the latest 2.8.x Symfony version, the latest Doctrine I was able to update via composer is 2.3.6-dev, which is pretty old, but it seems it is the latest supported/compatible.

Is it a known problem? Is Symfony 2.8 compatible with PHP 7.0?
Can you give me some advices on how to solve this?

My Form Type:

```
$qb = array(
    'class' => 'Prfuk\\WebquotaBundle\\Entity\\Workplace',
    'property' => 'nazev',
    'query_builder' => function(\Prfuk\WebquotaBundle\Entity\WorkplaceRepository $repository) {
        return $repository
            ->createQueryBuilder('s1')
            ->add('orderBy', 's1.nazev ASC');
    },
    'attr' => array(
        "class" => "input_text_nazev"),
        'label' => "Pracoviště",
    );
$builder->add('pracoviste', 'entity', $qb);
```

My Controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new FolderType($this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()), $folder);
if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
    //print_r($form->getData()); // works here
    $form->bind($request); // throws an exception
```

ORM:

```
Prfuk\WebquotaBundle\Entity\Folder:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: Prfuk\WebquotaBundle\Entity\FolderRepository
    fields:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
        nazev:
            type: string
            length: '255'
        cesta:
            type: string
            length: '255'
        kvota:
            type: integer
        uzivatel:
            type: string
            length: '255'
        poznamka:
            type: text
        vyuziti_mb:
            type: integer
            options:
                default: 0
    manyToOne:
        pracoviste:
            targetEntity: Workplace
            inversedBy: pracoviste
            joinColumn:
                name: pracoviste
                referencedColumnName: id
        db:
            targetEntity: DatabaseInfo
            inversedBy: db
            joinColumn:
                name: db
                referencedColumnName: id
        skupina:
            targetEntity: GroupInfo
            inversedBy: skupina
            joinColumn:
                name: skupina
                referencedColumnName: id
        webhost:
            targetEntity: WebhostInfo
            inversedBy: webhost
            joinColumn:
                name: webhost
                referencedColumnName: id
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

EDIT: stacktrace (file paths redacted):

```
[1] Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 63: Error: Expected Literal, got 'ORDER'
    at n/a
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php line 44

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException::syntaxError('line 0, col 63: Error: Expected Literal, got 'ORDER'', object(QueryException))
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 396

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->syntaxError('Literal')
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 2363

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->Literal()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 2550

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->ArithmeticPrimary()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 2485

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->ArithmeticFactor()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 2453

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->ArithmeticTerm()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 2427

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->SimpleArithmeticExpression()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 2414

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->ArithmeticExpression()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 2749

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->ComparisonExpression()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 2277

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->SimpleConditionalExpression()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 2177

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->ConditionalPrimary()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 2153

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->ConditionalFactor()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 2121

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->ConditionalTerm()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 2096

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->ConditionalExpression()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 1209

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->WhereClause()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 759

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->SelectStatement()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 726

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->QueryLanguage()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 229

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->getAST()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 304

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->parse()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query.php line 233

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query->_parse()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query.php line 245

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query->_doExecute()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php line 753

    at Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery->execute(null, '1')
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php line 542

    at Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery->getResult()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/ChoiceList/ORMQueryBuilderLoader.php line 126

    at Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\ChoiceList\ORMQueryBuilderLoader->getEntitiesByIds('id', array('27'))
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/ChoiceList/DoctrineChoiceLoader.php line 153

    at Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\ChoiceList\DoctrineChoiceLoader->loadChoicesForValues(array('27'), array(object(IdReader), 'getIdValue'))
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ChoiceList/LazyChoiceList.php line 122

    at Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\LazyChoiceList->getChoicesForValues(array('27'))
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataTransformer/ChoiceToValueTransformer.php line 46

    at Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataTransformer\ChoiceToValueTransformer->reverseTransform('27')
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php line 1190

    at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->viewToNorm('27')
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php line 639

    at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->submit('27', true)
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php line 579

    at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->submit(array('pracoviste' => '27', 'cesta' => 'simonju_botazah', 'kvota' => '100', 'uzivatel' => 'simonju', 'skupina' => '', 'poznamka' => 'fake záznam pro člena skupiny www-botazah', 'db' => '', 'webhost' => '', 'vyuziti_mb' => '0'))
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php line 692

    at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->bind(object(Request))
        in /..../Symfony/src/Prfuk/WebquotaBundle/Controller/FolderController.php line 90

    at Prfuk\WebquotaBundle\Controller\FolderController->editAction(object(Request), '650')
        in  line 

    at call_user_func_array(array(object(FolderController), 'editAction'), array(object(Request), '650'))
        in /..../Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3247

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
        in /..../Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3206

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
        in /..../Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3360

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
        in /..../Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2562

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
        in /..../Symfony/web/app_dev.php line 28

[2] Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: SELECT s1 FROM Prfuk\WebquotaBundle\Entity\Workplace s1 WHERE  ORDER BY s1.nazev ASC
    at n/a
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php line 39

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException::dqlError('SELECT s1 FROM Prfuk\WebquotaBundle\Entity\Workplace s1 WHERE  ORDER BY s1.nazev ASC')
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 396

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->syntaxError('Literal')
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 2363

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->Literal()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 2550

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->ArithmeticPrimary()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 2485

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->ArithmeticFactor()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 2453

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->ArithmeticTerm()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 2427

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->SimpleArithmeticExpression()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 2414

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->ArithmeticExpression()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 2749

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->ComparisonExpression()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 2277

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->SimpleConditionalExpression()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 2177

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->ConditionalPrimary()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 2153

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->ConditionalFactor()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 2121

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->ConditionalTerm()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 2096

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->ConditionalExpression()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 1209

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->WhereClause()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 759

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->SelectStatement()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 726

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->QueryLanguage()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 229

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->getAST()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 304

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->parse()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query.php line 233

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query->_parse()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query.php line 245

    at Doctrine\ORM\Query->_doExecute()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php line 753

    at Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery->execute(null, '1')
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php line 542

    at Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery->getResult()
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/ChoiceList/ORMQueryBuilderLoader.php line 126

    at Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\ChoiceList\ORMQueryBuilderLoader->getEntitiesByIds('id', array('27'))
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/ChoiceList/DoctrineChoiceLoader.php line 153

    at Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\ChoiceList\DoctrineChoiceLoader->loadChoicesForValues(array('27'), array(object(IdReader), 'getIdValue'))
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ChoiceList/LazyChoiceList.php line 122

    at Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\LazyChoiceList->getChoicesForValues(array('27'))
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataTransformer/ChoiceToValueTransformer.php line 46

    at Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataTransformer\ChoiceToValueTransformer->reverseTransform('27')
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php line 1190

    at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->viewToNorm('27')
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php line 639

    at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->submit('27', true)
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php line 579

    at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->submit(array('pracoviste' => '27', 'cesta' => 'simonju_botazah', 'kvota' => '100', 'uzivatel' => 'simonju', 'skupina' => '', 'poznamka' => 'fake záznam pro člena skupiny www-botazah', 'db' => '', 'webhost' => '', 'vyuziti_mb' => '0'))
        in /..../Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php line 692

    at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->bind(object(Request))
        in /..../Symfony/src/Prfuk/WebquotaBundle/Controller/FolderController.php line 90

    at Prfuk\WebquotaBundle\Controller\FolderController->editAction(object(Request), '650')
        in  line 

    at call_user_func_array(array(object(FolderController), 'editAction'), array(object(Request), '650'))
        in /..../Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3247

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
        in /..../Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3206

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
        in /..../Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3360

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
        in /..../Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2562

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
        in /..../Symfony/web/app_dev.php line 28
```

Comment: Are you sure you have 2.8 because Form::bind was depreciated way back in 2.3.  And Doctrine should be 2.5.  I suspect your app is much older then you might realize.

Comment: yes, it's 2.8.22. The method is deprecated, but until 3.0 it is there. I also tried to use submit() and handleRequest(), both gave me the same result.

Comment: I didn't figure out how to change composer.json to get more recent doctrine. 2.4 and 2.5 just give errors in dependencies check.

Comment: What I do is to install a fresh project then use it's composer.json as a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem:

1. old doctrine packages (2.3.x) which were for some reason not updated in February when I upgraded Symfony to 2.8 (I didn't even know as long as the composer was happy).
2. with the help of backtrace generated by app_dev.php, I narrowed the bug down to the andWhere() method of Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php:

   ```
   public function andWhere($where)
   {
       $where = $this->getDQLPart('where');
       $args  = func_get_args();
       if ($where instanceof Expr\Andx) {
           $where->addMultiple($args);
       } else {
           array_unshift($args, $where);
           $where = new Expr\Andx($args);
       }
       return $this->add('where', $where, true);
   }
   ```

There is a change in behaviour for func_get_args() since PHP 7.0.0:

> This function returns a copy of the passed arguments only, and does
>   not account for default (non-passed) arguments.
>
> If the arguments are passed by reference, any changes to the arguments
>   will be reflected in the values returned by this function. As of PHP 7
>   the current values will also be returned if the arguments are passed
>   by value.

The short-term solution was to swap first two lines of code in this method. But there are more places in the code using the same logical schema, so I was  an imperative for me to found a way to upgrade doctrine.

3. Upgrading doctrine turned out to be a hard task for me, but I succeded. Here is the final composer.json I have now:

   ```
   {
       "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
       "license": "MIT",
       "type": "project",
       "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
       "autoload": {
           "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
       },
       "require": {
           "php": ">=5.3.9",
           "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
           "doctrine/common": "2.5.*",
           "doctrine/dbal": "2.5.*",
           "doctrine/orm": "~2.5.0",
           "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4.0",
           "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
           "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
           "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
           "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
           "sensio/distribution-bundle": "4.0.*",
           "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "3.0.*",
           "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.4.*",
           "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.6.*",
           "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.4.*",
           "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0"
       },
       "minimum-stability": "stable",
       "scripts": {
           "post-install-cmd": [
               "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler       \\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
               "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
               "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
               "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
               "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
           ],
           "post-update-cmd": [
               "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
               "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
               "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
               "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
               "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
           ]
       },
       "config": {
           "bin-dir": "bin"
       },
       "extra": {
           "symfony-app-dir": "app",
           "symfony-web-dir": "web",
           "incenteev-parameters": {
                "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. With the new knowledge I was abelt to find more relevant info on the web, i.e.
   https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/4712

Thank you all who responded.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'query_builder' => function(\Prfuk\WebquotaBundle\Entity\WorkplaceRepository $repository) {
        return $repository
            ->createQueryBuilder('s1')
            ->orderBy('s1.nazev','ASC');
    },
```

Comment: It does not make any difference. In addition, if I omit the ordering, the problem persists. SQL error message just changes to  'QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col -1: Error: Expected Literal, got end of string.', probably as expected.

Comment: I think the problem is not in the QueryBuilder itself, as it works in other situations well (i.e. when I open the record to for editing, the html form fields are populated with correct data. I suppose the problem is somewhere in code which pairs request and form data and the WHERE clause with record ID is not passed to the QueryBuilder correctly. And interesting is that the problem is not in PHP 5.6, only in 7, so maybe there is some php version-dependent code. PHP 7 has removed some deprecated functions, but there are no such errors in logs, which would indicate use of non-existent functions.